# How to get someone else's live chat id via the youtube api

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Someone has asked me to make them a chat bot on youtube, and I seem to only be able get info from the api for my channel, can you use it to get info from someone else's channel?

this is the call im making, I'm trying to get the liveChatID to make other api calls

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts

part=snippet
id=ID_OF_BROADCAST

Comment: Purple Army? Cx

Answer (score 1):

Much like what you do for your own, you'll need to register an application that your client authorises.

You basically have two options:

1. Create an automated web service, and instruct your client to navigate to your web service, which, if properly setup, will guide the user through the "Do you allow this application 'My-Chat-Bot' to: " and then show a list of scopes.
2. Log onto the [Developer API Console](https://console.developers.google.com), and manually set up an app and a credential, then proceed to download the client secret json file and implement it to your "Chat Bot"

Also, see this article for further info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens

Comment: okay thanks, was hoping i didnt have to do that but its not much more work

Comment: @JamieKeelen Yeah, at least with option 2 it only takes a couple minutes, and it's a one-off.